# nginx: how to get the actual client ip?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, ip

I have a simple express app. which is `Dockerized`. This is [Repository](https://github.com/ashiqdev/exp-nginx-docker).

I used `nginx` as a reverse proxy there. when I visit `http://45.33.97.232:3000`, it gives me the actual *IP*.
But, when I visit `http://45.33.97.232/`, It gives me the same server *IP*. But I need actual `Client IP` here.
And I am using *Server IP* in `nginx` config file. but I have a restriction, I can't write *Server IP* in `nginx` config file.

This is my `nginx` config file,

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name 45.33.97.232;
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://45.33.97.232:3000; #port where you are serving your express app.
  }
}
```

Comment: In Express there's a convenient property on the Request object `req.ip` that gives you the IP of the client from either the remote IP from the connection or the IP address from `x-forwared-for` header depending on the `trust proxy` setting.

Comment: after adding `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;` in nginx config I am getting the correct IP. but how can I avoid writing server IP in nginx config file?

Comment: `server_name` is optional and is only required when you use a single Nginx instance to handle multiple virtual servers (multiple domains) and typically you configure it with the server's domain name

Answer (score 0):

In nginx if you want to pass through the IP address of the remote user to your backend web server you have to set X-Forwarded-For header to this remote ip, Like this:

`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;`

and if you do not want to use server IP you can use the domain in your Nginx config file.